# How to add a <select> or combobox inside CTKEditor text area

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm working with the CKEditor editor on a angular web application for filling in clinical reports. The reports will sometimes come with combobox/dropdowns where the user can select from a list of values based on their findings. This saves time and also adds a measure of validation since the user can't just put any value. I tried to manually add this to the body of the editor:

```
<select>
  <option value="Empty"></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I have have the

```
  CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

then I get a combobox, but I can't select a value

[image: Dropdown in CKEditor]

Anyone know of an easyish way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The [Forms](http://ckeditor.com/addon/forms) plugin does the same thing, but again I can't select anything from the dropdown. It doesn't respond to clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't get this to work with CKEditor, I've looked at alternatives namely [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) and [Summernote](http://summernote.org/#/). Both of which offer support for angular and allow me put an inline dropdown in the text area, which I can change the value of. In addition they both support multiple environments/browsers. If anyone knows of an editor with similar capabilities, then please let me know.